# Make a circle illusion animation

Tags: popularity-contest, graphical-output, animation

Your job is to animate this [circle illusion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNe6fsaCVtI). It looks like the points rotating inside of the circle, but they are actually just moving in straight lines.

[image]

## Criterias

- The result has to be animated. The way you do the animation is irrelevant, it can generate a `.gif`, it can draw to a window, some device screen or whatever.
- This is a popularity contest, so you might want to add some additional features to your program to get more upvotes, for example varying the number of points.
- The winner is the most upvoted **valid** answer 7 days after the last valid submission.
- **The answers that will actually implement points moving on straight lines and not another way around are more welcomed**

Comment: "winner is the most upvoted valid after 7 days". So if someone posts something every 6 days until the stars die, we have no winner?

Comment: @KevinL that is unlikely to happen and I don't think those 15 extra rep are that important compared to all the upvotes you'd get from this question being bumped to the top every 6 days.

Comment: @KevinL: If that happens, we will have a winner after the stars die.

Comment: look closely, and focus on any one of the balls. They are just oscillating along one of their pass axis.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if some people do these just to get a job done...

Comment: @DantheMan I really enjoyed this question... I think I know what you mean - that need to do something that can be finished quickly for a sense of completion.

Comment: "It looks like the points rotating inside of the circle, but they are actually just moving in straight lines.", or, maybe they are really rotating inside a circle and *appear* to move in straight lines ...

Comment: Can't.. get this animation.. out of my mind.. especially the 3-point version!

Answer (score 133, accepted):

## Python 3.4

Using the turtle module. The turtles are different colours and they always face in the same direction, so they can be easily seen to be moving along straight lines by just focusing on one of them. Despite this the circle illusion is still strong.

[image: 11 turtles]

The illusion still seems quite strong even with just 3 or 4 turtles:

[image: 3 turtles][image: 4 turtles]

The framerate is reduced considerably for all of these GIF examples, but it doesn't seem to detract from the illusion. Running the code locally gives a smoother animation.

```python
import turtle
import time
from math import sin, pi
from random import random


def circle_dance(population=11, resolution=480, loops=1, flip=0, lines=0):
    population = int(population)
    resolution = int(resolution)
    radius = 250
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.tracer(0)
    if lines:
        arrange_lines(population, radius)
    turtles = [turtle.Turtle() for i in range(population)]
    for i in range(population):
        dancer = turtles[i]
        make_dancer(dancer, i, population)
    animate(turtles, resolution, screen, loops, flip, radius)


def arrange_lines(population, radius):
    artist = turtle.Turtle()
    for n in range(population):
        artist.penup()
        artist.setposition(0, 0)
        artist.setheading(n / population * 180)
        artist.forward(-radius)
        artist.pendown()
        artist.forward(radius * 2)
    artist.hideturtle()


def make_dancer(dancer, i, population):
    dancer.setheading(i / population * 180)
    dancer.color(random_turtle_colour())
    dancer.penup()
    dancer.shape('turtle')
    dancer.turtlesize(2)


def random_turtle_colour():
    return random() * 0.9, 0.5 + random() * 0.5, random() * 0.7


def animate(turtles, resolution, screen, loops, flip, radius):
    delay = 4 / resolution      # 4 seconds per repetition
    while True:
        for step in range(resolution):
            timer = time.perf_counter()
            phase = step / resolution * 2 * pi
            draw_dancers(turtles, phase, screen, loops, flip, radius)
            elapsed = time.perf_counter() - timer
            adjusted_delay = max(0, delay - elapsed)
            time.sleep(adjusted_delay)


def draw_dancers(turtles, phase, screen, loops, flip, radius):
    population = len(turtles)
    for i in range(population):
        individual_phase = (phase + i / population * loops * pi) % (2*pi)
        dancer = turtles[i]
        if flip:
            if pi / 2 < individual_phase <= 3 * pi / 2:
                dancer.settiltangle(180)
            else:
                dancer.settiltangle(0)
        distance = radius * sin(individual_phase)
        dancer.setposition(0, 0)
        dancer.forward(distance)
    screen.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    circle_dance(*(float(n) for n in sys.argv[1:]))
```

#### For contrast here are some that really do rotate:

[image: 23 loop turtles][image: 23 trefoil turtles]

#### ...or do they?

The code can be run with 5 optional arguments: population, resolution, loops, flip and lines.

- `population` is the number of turtles
- `resolution` is the time resolution (number of animation frames per repetition)
- `loops` determines how many times the turtles loop back on themselves. The default of 1 gives a standard circle, other odd numbers give that number of loops in the string of turtles, while even numbers give a string of turtles disconnected at the ends, but still with the illusion of curved motion.
- `flip` if non-zero causes the turtles to flip direction for their return trip (as suggested by [aslum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17277/aslum) so that they are never moving backwards). As default they keep a fixed direction to avoid the visual distraction at the endpoints.
- `lines` if non-zero displays the lines on which the turtles move, for consistency with the example image in the question.

Examples with `flip` set, with and without `lines`. I've left my main example above without flip as I prefer not to have the sporadic jump, but the edge of the circle does look smoother with all the turtles aligned, so the option is there for people to choose whichever style they prefer when running the code.

[image: 11 turtles with flip and lines][image: 11 turtles with flip]

It might not be immediately obvious how the images above were all produced from this same code. In particular the image further up which has a slow outer loop and a fast inner loop (the one that looks like a cardioid that someone accidentally dropped). I've hidden the explanation of this one below in case anyone wants to delay finding out while experimenting/thinking.

> The animation with an inner and outer loop of different sizes was created by setting the number of loops to 15 and leaving the number of turtles at 23 (too low to represent 15 loops). Using a large number of turtles would result in 15 clearly defined loops. Using too few turtles results in aliasing (for the same reason as in image processing and rendering). Trying to represent too high a frequency results in a lower frequency being displayed, with distortion.

Trying out different numbers I found some of these distortions more interesting than the more symmetrical originals, so I wanted to include one here...

Comment: I like turtles.

Comment: I shelled out +1 for the turtles

Comment: @ProgramFOX thanks for the syntax highlighting! I searched through the help and meta and convinced myself we didn't have syntax highlighting on code golf - I'm much happier with this now.

Comment: Hey, what would happen if turtles will also rotate?

Comment: @swish you could try it if you like - the code is there to be used. It wouldn't be a valid answer to this question, but if you post it somewhere else you could melt people's brains with it...

Comment: Only improvement would be if the turtles flipped 180 degrees when they changed directions... so they are always going 'forward'.

Comment: @aslum that would be a straightforward change to make, but I wanted their orientation frozen to really emphasise that they do not deviate from their straight line course. Maybe I should add it to the code as an option so people can choose the approach they prefer.

Comment: @aslum since someone upvoted my comment saying maybe I should, I've added the option to flip the turtle directions. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: +1 - It'd be awesome to see a marching band do some of these funkier ones!

Answer (score 98):

## C

Result:

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Math.h>

int round (double r) { return (r > 0.0) ? (r + 0.5) : (r - 0.5); }
void print (int x, int y, char c) {
    COORD p = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), p);
    printf("%c", c);
}

int main ()
{
    float pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
    float circle = pi * 2;
    int len = 12;
    int hlen = len / 2;
    int cx = 13;
    int cy = 8;
    float w = 11.0;
    float h =  8.0;
    float step = 0.0;

    while (1)
    {
        system("cls"); // xD

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            float a = (i / (float)len) * circle;
            int x = cx + round(cos(a) * w);
            int y = cy + round(sin(a) * h);
            print(x, y, 'O');

            if (i < hlen) continue;

            step -= 0.05;
            float range = cos(a + step);
            x = cx + round(cos(a) * (w - 1) * range);
            y = cy + round(sin(a) * (h - 1) * range);
            print(x, y, 'O');
        }

        Sleep(100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In some frames it's a bit off. But congrats for doing it in ASCII!

Comment: +1 for ASCII and `system("cls"); // xD`

Comment: This is beautiful.

Comment: [This one works on linux.](http://pastebin.com/Q4f8igMs) (although quite miserably)

Comment: Obligatory hater comment: "This isn't C! The standard doesn't define Sleep, COORD or SetConsoleCursorPosition!"

Answer (score 55):

## SVG (no Javascript)

[JSFiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/xh3Tj/)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 380 380" width="380" height="380" version="1.0">
  <g transform="translate(190 190)">
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="190" fill="#000"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="-190" x2="0" y2="190" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    <line x1="72.71" y1="175.54" x2="-72.71" y2="-175.54" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    <line x1="134.35" y1="134.35" x2="-134.35" y2="-134.35" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    <line x1="175.54" y1="72.71" x2="-175.54" y2="-72.71" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    <line x1="190" y1="0" x2="-190" y2="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    <line x1="175.54" y1="-72.71" x2="-175.54" y2="72.71" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    <line x1="134.35" y1="-134.35" x2="-134.35" y2="134.35" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    <line x1="72.71" y1="-175.54" x2="-72.71" y2="175.54" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    <g transform="rotate(0)">
      <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" begin="0" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      <g transform="translate(0 90)">
        <g transform="rotate(0)">
          <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0" to="-360" begin="0" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
          <circle cx="0" cy="90" r="10" fill="#fff"/>
          <circle cx="63.64" cy="63.64" r="10" fill="#fff"/>
          <circle cx="90" cy="0" r="10" fill="#fff"/>
          <circle cx="63.64" cy="-63.64" r="10" fill="#fff"/>
          <circle cx="0" cy="-90" r="10" fill="#fff"/>
          <circle cx="-63.64" cy="-63.64" r="10" fill="#fff"/>
          <circle cx="-90" cy="0" r="10" fill="#fff"/>
          <circle cx="-63.64" cy="63.64" r="10" fill="#fff"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm sure this passes muster with the rules, but I was, personally, disappointed that you are in fact doing the opposite. Rather than “It looks like the points [are] rotating inside of the circle, but they are actually just **moving in straight lines**.”, yours implements: “It looks like the points [are] moving in straight lines, but they are actually just **rotating inside of the circle**.”

Comment: Smoothest answer!

Comment: @mkoistinen I see what you mean, but the points *really are* moving in straight lines. It just happens to be easier to calculate their positions with two rotations :-)

Comment: Did you do it all 'by hand' or did you use any kind of (non-text-) editor?

Comment: @flawr I just used a [plain text editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextWrangler#TextWrangler) and the calculator in my phone to work out the numbers :-)

Answer (score 48):

http://jsfiddle.net/z6vhD/13/

`intervaltime` changes the FPS (FPS = 1000/intervaltime).
`balls` changes the # balls.
`maxstep` adjusts the # steps in a cycle, the larger the 'smoother' it is. 64 should be large enough where it appears smooth.

Modeled as a circle moving, instead of moving the balls along the lines, but the visual effect (should be?) the same. Some of the code is pretty verbose, but this isn't code golf, so...

```
var intervalTime = 40;
var balls = 8;
var maxstep = 64;

var canvas = $('#c').get(0); // 100% necessary jquery
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var step = 0;

animateWorld = function() {
    createBase();
    step = step % maxstep;
    var centerX = canvas.width/2 + 115 * Math.cos(step * 2 / maxstep * Math.PI);
    var centerY = canvas.height/2 + 115 * Math.sin(step * 2 / maxstep * Math.PI);

    for (var i=0; i<balls; i++) {
        drawCircle(ctx, (centerX + 115 * Math.cos((i * 2 / balls - step * 2 / maxstep) * Math.PI)), (centerY + 115 * Math.sin((i * 2 / balls - step * 2 / maxstep) * Math.PI)), 10, '#FFFFFF');     
    }

    step++;
}

function createBase() {
    drawCircle(ctx, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 240, '#000000');
    for(var i=0; i<balls*2; i++) {
        drawLine(ctx, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, canvas.width/2 + 240 * Math.cos(i / balls * Math.PI), canvas.height/2 + 240 * Math.sin(i / balls * Math.PI), '#FFFFFF');
    }
}

function drawLine(context, x1, y1, x2, y2, c) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x1,y1);
    context.lineTo(x2,y2);
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.strokeStyle = c;
    context.stroke();
}

function drawCircle(context, x, y, r, c) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = c;
    context.fill();
}

function drawRect(context, x, y, w, h, c) {
    context.fillStyle = c;
    context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    intervalID = window.setInterval(animateWorld, intervalTime);
});
```

Comment: It's so smooth! Very nice.

Comment: Don't use setInterval for animations, take [`requestAnimationFrame` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame).

[Modified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6vhD/54/) using `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: With just a few parameter tweaks you get a [very different thing](http://jsfiddle.net/z6vhD/143/).

Comment: @KevinL Yep, just noticed that too. Updated.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Oh, when you said very different thing, I thought you meant like the ones in http://jsfiddle.net/z6vhD/100/

Comment: Heh, that's cool too.

Comment: +1 for using `balls` as a variable.  Instead of drawing `balls * 2` radii you could draw `balls` diameters for a small savings.

Answer (score 43):

#### CSS animations

A solution using only css animations (see animation [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nBCxz/6/) - note that I added the browser specific prefixes in the fiddle so that it can work in most recent versions).

```
<body>
    <div id="w1"></div>
    <div id="w2"></div>
    <div id="w3"></div>
    <div id="w4"></div>
    <div id="w5"></div>
    <div id="w6"></div>
    <div id="w7"></div>
    <div id="w8"></div>
</body>


div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: red;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#w1 { animation-name: s1; animation-delay: 0.0s }
#w2 { animation-name: s2; animation-delay: 0.5s }
#w3 { animation-name: s3; animation-delay: 1.0s }
#w4 { animation-name: s4; animation-delay: 1.5s }
#w5 { animation-name: s5; animation-delay: 2.0s }
#w6 { animation-name: s6; animation-delay: 2.5s }
#w7 { animation-name: s7; animation-delay: 3.0s }
#w8 { animation-name: s8; animation-delay: 3.5s }

@keyframes s1 { from {top: 100px; left:   0px;} to {top: 100px; left: 200px;} } 
@keyframes s2 { from {top:  62px; left:   8px;} to {top: 138px; left: 192px;} } 
@keyframes s3 { from {top:  29px; left:  29px;} to {top: 171px; left: 171px;} } 
@keyframes s4 { from {top:   8px; left:  62px;} to {top: 192px; left: 138px;} } 
@keyframes s5 { from {top:   0px; left: 100px;} to {top: 200px; left: 100px;} } 
@keyframes s6 { from {top:   8px; left: 138px;} to {top: 192px; left:  62px;} } 
@keyframes s7 { from {top:  29px; left: 171px;} to {top: 171px; left:  29px;} } 
@keyframes s8 { from {top:  62px; left: 192px;} to {top: 138px; left:   8px;} }
```

Comment: Fiddle not working for me on latest Chrome =/

Comment: @mkoistinen - You have to add different prefixes for it to be working in different browsers. (`-webkit-` for Webkit-based and `-moz-` for Mozilla-based) Here is the same fiddle with updated prefixes: http://jsfiddle.net/nBCxz/3/

Comment: @mkoistinen You're right. The new fiddle adds all necessary browser prefixes and works on latest Chrome.

Comment: The raw link text is just missing the closing parenthesis - still perfectly usable just letting you know in case you wanted to fix it (I can't as it's less than 6 characters to change).

Answer (score 38):

### Mathematica

Here is a pretty straight-forward submission.

```
animateCircle[n_] := Animate[Graphics[
   Flatten@{
     Disk[],
     White,
     Map[
      (
        phase = #*2 \[Pi]/n;
        line = {Cos[phase], Sin[phase]};
        {Line[{-line, line}],
         Disk[Sin[t + phase]*line, 0.05]}
        ) &,
      Range[n]
      ]
     },
   PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}
   ],
  {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
  ]
```

If you call `animateCircle[32]` you'll get a neat animation with 32 lines and circles.

[image]

It's completely smooth in Mathematica, but I had to limit the number of frames for the GIF a bit.

Now what happens if you put two discs on each line? (That is, add `Disk[-Sin[t + phase]*line, 0.05]` to the list within the `Map`.)

[image]

You can also put them 90° out of phase (use `Cos` instead of `-Sin`):

[image]

Comment: I dunno what glitches do you mean, probably you need to change `{t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}` to `{t, 0, 2 \[Pi] - 2 \[Pi]/60, 2 \[Pi]/60}` so that there won't be two identical frames and change `Animate` to `Table`. Then you'll be able to export GIF.

Comment: @swish No it actually renders weird additional lines that aren't there and the discs in places where they shouldn't be (and where they never are in the actual result of `Animate`). I'll try using `Table` again though.

Comment: @swish That worked. I thought I tried something like this yesterday, but apparently I didn't.

Answer (score 27):

## Excel (no VBA)

[image: Excel]

```
=2*PI()*(NOW()*24*60*60/A2-FLOOR(NOW()*24*60*60/A2,1))
=ROUND(7*SIN(A1),0)
=ROUND(5*SIN(A1+1*PI()/4),0)
=ROUND(7*SIN(A1+2*PI()/4),0)
=ROUND(5*SIN(A1+3*PI()/4),0)
```

A2 (period) determines the time (seconds) for a full 'revolution'.

Each cell within the lines is a basic conditional relating to the value of the corresponding line.  For example, K2 is:

```
 =1*(A5=7)
```

And the center cell (K9) is:

```
=1*OR(A5=0,A6=0,A7=0,A8=0)
```

Forced the animation by holding 'delete' on a random cell to constantly trigger a refresh.

I know this is an old topic, but recent activity brought it to the top and it seemed appealing for some reason.  Long time pcg listener, first time caller.  Be gentle.

Comment: Wow, that's incredible that you can do that with Excel :D

Answer (score 26):

### VBScript + VBA + Excel Pie Chart

This will make your processor cry a little but it looks pretty and I believe it works according to spec. I used @Fabricio's answer as a guide to implement the circle movement algorithm.

EDIT: Made some adjustments to improve render speed.

[image: Screenshot of Pie chart]

The code:

```vb
'Open Excel
Set objX = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objX.Visible = True
objX.Workbooks.Add

'Populate values
objX.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Lbl"
objX.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Amt"
For fillX = 2 to 17
    objX.Cells(fillX, 1).Value = "V"+Cstr(fillX-1)
    objX.Cells(fillX, 2).Value = "1"
Next

'Create pie
objX.Range("A2:B17").Select
objX.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
With objX.ActiveChart
    .ChartType = 5 'pieChart
    .SetSourceData  objX.Range("$A$2:$B$17")
    .SeriesCollection(1).Select
End with    

'Format pie
With objX.Selection.Format
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 0 'black
    .Fill.Solid
    .Line.Weight = 2
    .Line.Visible = 1
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = 16777215 'white
End With

'animation variables
pi = 3.14159265358979323846
circle = pi * 2 : l  = 16.0
hlen = l / 2    : cx = 152.0
cy = 99.0       : w  = 90.0
h  = 90.0       : s  = 0.0
Dim posArry(7,1)

'Animate
While 1 
  For i = 0 to hlen-1
    a = (i / l) * circle
    range = cos(a + s)
    x = cx + cos(a) * w * range
    y = cy + sin(a) * h * range

    If whileInx = 1 Then 
        createOval x, y
    ElseIf whileInx = 2 Then 
        objX.ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    ElseIf whileInx > 2 Then
        ovalName = "Oval "+ Cstr(i+1)
        dx = x - posArry(i,0)
        dy = y - posArry(i,1)
        moveOval ovalName, dx, dy
    End if

    posArry(i,0) = x
    posArry(i,1) = y
  Next

  s=s-0.05
  wscript.Sleep 1000/60 '60fps
  whileInx = 1 + whileInx
Wend

'create circles
sub createOval(posX, posY)
    objX.ActiveChart.Shapes.AddShape(9, posX, posY, 10, 10).Select '9=oval
    objX.Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = 0
    with objX.Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
       .Visible = 1
       .ForeColor.RGB = 16777215 'white
       .solid
    end with
end sub

'move circles
sub moveOval(ovalName, dx, dy)
    with objX.ActiveChart.Shapes(ovalName)      
        .IncrementLeft dx
        .IncrementTop  dy
    end with
end sub
```

Comment: It crashes for me at line 81, error 80070057, "element with the given name does not exist" or something like this (translated back from Hungarian, that's why I don't know the exact error message).

Comment: Szervusz, @marczellm. I can reproduce that error when I click outside of the chart while it is "animating". You have to allow it focus or the program will error. Otherwise, this may be due to an incompatibility with Office. I'm on Office 2010 on Win7.

Comment: Office 2007, Win7. Seems like in my case the chart doesn't get focus at all.

Answer (score 17):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\psset{unit=.3}

% static point
% #1 : half of the number of points
% #2 : ith point
\def\x[#1,#2]{(3*cos(Pi/#1*#2))}
\def\y[#1,#2]{(3*sin(Pi/#1*#2))}

% oscillated point
% #1 : half of the number of points
% #2 : ith point
% #3 : time parameter
\def\X[#1,#2]#3{(\x[#1,#2]*cos(#3+Pi/#1*#2))}
\def\Y[#1,#2]#3{(\y[#1,#2]*cos(#3+Pi/#1*#2))}

% single frame
% #1 : half of the number of points
% #2 : time parameter
\def\Frame#1#2{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pstVerb{/I2P {AlgParser cvx exec} bind def}%
    \pscircle*{\dimexpr3\psunit+2pt\relax}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{\psline[linecolor=yellow](!\x[#1,\i] I2P \y[#1,\i] I2P)(!\x[#1,\i] I2P neg \y[#1,\i] I2P neg)}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{\pscircle*[linecolor=white](!\X[#1,\i]{#2} I2P \Y[#1,\i]{#2} I2P){2pt}}   
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\foreach \t in {0,...,24}
{   
    \preview
    \Frame{1}{2*Pi*\t/25} \quad \Frame{2}{2*Pi*\t/25} \quad \Frame{3}{2*Pi*\t/25} \quad \Frame{5}{2*Pi*\t/25} \quad \Frame{10}{2*Pi*\t/25}
    \endpreview
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Fortran**

Each frame is created as an individual gif file using the Fortran gif module at: http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/writegif
Then I cheat a little by using ImageMagick to merge the individual gifs into one animated gif.

[image: Fortran]

UPDATE: Set new = .true. to get the following:

[image]

```
program circle_illusion

use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: wp=>real64
use gif_util  !gif writing module from http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/writegif

implicit none

logical,parameter :: new = .false.

integer,parameter  :: n        = 500  !550  !size of image (square)     
real(wp),parameter :: rcircle  = n/2  !250  !radius of the big circle
integer,parameter  :: time_sep = 5    !deg

real(wp),parameter :: deg2rad = acos(-1.0_wp)/180.0_wp
integer,dimension(0:n,0:n):: pixel     ! pixel values
integer,dimension(3,0:3)  :: colormap  ! RGB 0:255 for colors 0:ncol    
real(wp),dimension(2)     :: xy
integer,dimension(2)      :: ixy
real(wp)                  :: r,t
integer                   :: i,j,k,row,col,m,n_cases,ang_sep
character(len=10)         :: istr

integer,parameter  :: black = 0
integer,parameter  :: white = 1
integer,parameter  :: red   = 2
integer,parameter  :: gray  = 3    
colormap(:,0) = [0,0,0]          !black
colormap(:,1) = [255,255,255]    !white
colormap(:,2) = [255,0,0]        !red
colormap(:,3) = [200,200,200]    !gray

if (new) then
    ang_sep = 5
    n_cases = 3
else
    ang_sep = 20
    n_cases = 0
end if

do k=0,355,time_sep

    !clear entire image:
    pixel = white      

    if (new) call draw_circle(n/2,n/2,black,n/2)  

    !draw polar grid:    
    do j=0,180-ang_sep,ang_sep
        do i=-n/2, n/2
            call spherical_to_cartesian(dble(i),dble(j)*deg2rad,xy)
            call convert(xy,row,col)
            if (new) then
                pixel(row,col) = gray
            else
                pixel(row,col) = black  
            end if  
        end do
    end do

    !draw dots:
    do m=0,n_cases
        do j=0,360-ang_sep,ang_sep
            r = sin(m*90.0_wp*deg2rad + (k + j)*deg2rad)*rcircle                
            t = dble(j)*deg2rad    
            call spherical_to_cartesian(r,t,xy)
            call convert(xy,row,col)
            if (new) then
                !call draw_circle(row,col,black,10)  !v2
                !call draw_circle(row,col,m,5)       !v2
                call draw_circle(row,col,white,10)   !v3
            else
                call draw_square(row,col,red)        !v1
            end if
        end do
    end do

    !write the gif file for this frame:        
    write(istr,'(I5.3)') k
    call writegif('gifs/test'//trim(adjustl(istr))//'.gif',pixel,colormap)

end do

!use imagemagick to make animated gif from all the frames:
! from: http://thanosk.net/content/create-animated-gif-linux
if (new) then
    call system('convert -delay 5 gifs/test*.gif -loop 0 animated.gif')
else
    call system('convert -delay 10 gifs/test*.gif -loop 0 animated.gif')
end if

!delete individual files:
call system('rm gifs/test*.gif')

contains

    subroutine draw_square(r,c,icolor)

    implicit none
    integer,intent(in) :: r,c  !row,col of center
    integer,intent(in) :: icolor

    integer,parameter :: d = 10 !square size

    pixel(max(0,r-d):min(n,r+d),max(0,c-d):min(n,c+d)) = icolor

    end subroutine draw_square

    subroutine draw_circle(r,c,icolor,d)

    implicit none
    integer,intent(in) :: r,c  !row,col of center
    integer,intent(in) :: icolor
    integer,intent(in) :: d  !diameter

    integer :: i,j

    do i=max(0,r-d),min(n,r+d)
        do j=max(0,c-d),min(n,c+d)
            if (sqrt(dble(i-r)**2 + dble(j-c)**2)<=d) &
                pixel(i,j) = icolor
        end do
    end do

    end subroutine draw_circle

    subroutine convert(xy,row,col)

    implicit none
    real(wp),dimension(2),intent(in) :: xy  !coordinates
    integer,intent(out) :: row,col

    row = int(-xy(2) + n/2.0_wp)
    col = int( xy(1) + n/2.0_wp)

    end subroutine convert

    subroutine spherical_to_cartesian(r,theta,xy)

    implicit none
    real(wp),intent(in) :: r,theta
    real(wp),dimension(2),intent(out) :: xy

    xy(1) = r * cos(theta)
    xy(2) = r * sin(theta)

    end subroutine spherical_to_cartesian

end program circle_illusion
```

Comment: I like the impact 'squish' for the vertical & horizontal elements.

Answer (score 12):

Mandatory **C64** version.

Copy&paste in your favorite emulator:

[image: C64 version]

```
1 print chr$(147)
2 poke 53281,0
3 for p=0 to 7
5 x=int(11+(cos(p*0.78)*10)):y=int(12+(sin(p*0.78)*10))
6 poke 1024+x+(y*40),15
9 next p
10 for sp=2040 to 2047:poke sp,13:next sp
20 for i=0 to 62:read a:poke 832+i,a:next i
30 for i=0 to 7:poke 53287+i,i+1:next i
40 rem activate sprites
50 poke 53269,255
60 an=0.0
70 rem maincycle
75 teta=0.0:k=an
80 for i=0 to 7
90 px=cos(k)*64
92 s=i:x=px*cos(teta): y=px*sin(teta): x=x+100: y=y+137: gosub 210
94 teta=teta+0.392699
95 k=k+0.392699
96 next i
130 an=an+0.1
140 goto 70
150 end
200 rem setspritepos
210 poke 53248+s*2,int(x): poke 53249+s*2,int(y)
220 return
5000 data 0,254,0
5010 data 3,199,128
5020 data 7,0,64
5030 data 12,126,96
5040 data 25,255,48
5050 data 59,7,152
5060 data 52,1,200
5070 data 116,0,204
5080 data 120,0,100
5090 data 120,0,100
5100 data 120,0,100
5110 data 120,0,36
5120 data 104,0,36
5130 data 100,0,108
5140 data 54,0,72
5150 data 51,0,152
5160 data 25,131,16
5170 data 12,124,96
5180 data 4,0,64
5190 data 3,1,128
5200 data 0,254,0
```

Answer (score 11):

A compact javascript version, changing the default settings to something different

http://jsfiddle.net/yZ3DP/1/

HTML:

```
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var v= document.getElementById('c');
var c= v.getContext('2d');
var w= v.width, w2= w/2;
var num= 28, M2= Math.PI*2, da= M2/num;
draw();
var bw= 10;
var time= 0;
function draw()
{
    v.width= w;
    c.beginPath();
    c.fillStyle= 'black';
    circle(w2,w2,w2);
    c.lineWidth= 1.5;
    c.strokeStyle= c.fillStyle= 'white';
    var a= 0;
    for (var i=0; i< num*2; i++){
        c.moveTo(w2,w2);
        c.lineTo(w2+Math.cos(a)*w2, w2+Math.sin(a)*w2);
        a+= da/2;
    }
    c.stroke();
    a= 0;
    for (var i=0; i< num; i++){
        circle(w2+Math.cos(a)*Math.sin(time+i*Math.PI/num)*(w2-bw), 
               w2+Math.sin(a)*Math.sin(time+i*Math.PI/num)*(w2-bw), bw);
        a+= da/2;
    }
    time+=0.03;
   requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function circle(x,y,r)
{
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x, y, r, 0, M2);
    c.fill();

}
```

Comment: You made ... a *doughnut*?? Actually your animation looks nice with smaller dots (try `bw=10`). Please edit your answer to show your code. Oh, and while you're at it, there's a bug you should fix: replace `time+i*0.39*0.29` with `time+i*Math.PI/num` in the trig calculations so that the coordinates are calculated correctly for any value of `num`. (P.S. [Updated JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yZ3DP/1/). And welcome to codegolf.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I just wanted to make something different (like the turtles one). Newbie here in codegolf :)

Oh, and thank you for the formula :D I just did it in a hurry and tried random values, didn't stop a minute  to get to the correct formula :P

Comment: +1 Small change for a little visual fun: [http://jsfiddle.net/9TQrm/](http://jsfiddle.net/9TQrm/) or [http://jsfiddle.net/Wrqs4/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Wrqs4/1/)

Answer (score 5):

My take with **Elm**. I am a total beginner who will happily accept PRs to improve this solution ([GitHub](https://github.com/netzwerg/elm-playground/blob/master/Circle.elm)):

[image]

Note that this submission is really moving points on straight lines:

```
import Color exposing (..)
import Graphics.Collage exposing (..)
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import Time exposing (..)
import Window
import List exposing (..)
import AnimationFrame -- "jwmerrill/elm-animation-frame"
import Debug

-- CONFIG

size = 600
circleSize = 240
dotCount = 12
dotSize = 10
velocity = 0.01

-- MODEL

type alias Dot =
    { x : Float
    , angle : Float
    }

type alias State = List Dot

createDots : State
createDots = map createDot [ 0 .. dotCount - 1 ]

createDot : Int -> Dot
createDot index =
    let angle = toFloat index * pi / dotCount
    in { x = 0
       , angle = angle
       }

-- UPDATE

update : Time -> State -> State
update time dots = map (moveDot time) dots |> Debug.watch "Dots"

moveDot : Time -> Dot -> Dot
moveDot time dot =
  let t = velocity * time / pi
      newX = (-circleSize + dotSize) * cos(t + dot.angle)
  in { dot | x <- newX }

-- VIEW

view : State -> Element
view dots =
   let background = filled black (circle circleSize)
       dotLinePairs = map viewDotWithLine dots
   in collage size size (background :: dotLinePairs)

viewDotWithLine : Dot -> Form
viewDotWithLine dot =
  let dotView = viewDot dot
      lineView = createLineView
  in group [dotView , lineView] |> rotate dot.angle

viewDot : Dot -> Form
viewDot d = alpha 0.8 (filled lightOrange (circle dotSize)) |> move (d.x, 0)

createLineView : Form
createLineView = traced (solid white) (path [ (-size / 2.0, 0) , (size / 2.0, 0) ])

-- SIGNALS

main = Signal.map view (animate createDots)

animate : State -> Signal State
animate dots = Signal.foldp update dots time

time = Signal.foldp (+) 0 AnimationFrame.frame
```

Comment: That cursor fooled me good, and mine isn't even black or that size.

Answer (score 3):

Second Life LSL

[image: animation]
start of turtle alpha image (right click below to save image)
[image: turtle.png]
end of turtle alpha image (right click above to save image)
building the object:
make a root prim cylinder size <1, 1, 0.01> slice 0.49, 0.51, color <0, 0, 0>
make the description of this cylinder "8,1,1,1" without the quotes (very important)
make a cylinder, name it "cyl", color <0.25, 0.25, 0.25> alpha 0.5
duplicate the cyl 48 times
make a box, name it "sphere", color <1, 1, 1> transparency 100 except for the top transparency 0
put your turtle texture on face 0 of the box, turtle should face +x
duplicate the box 48 times
select all the boxes and the cylinders, make sure to select the root cylinder last, link (control L)

put these 2 scripts in the root:

```
//script named "dialog"
default
{
    state_entry()
    {

    }

    link_message(integer link, integer num, string msg, key id)
    {
        list msgs = llCSV2List(msg);
        key agent = (key)llList2String(msgs, 0);
        string prompt = llList2String(msgs, 1);
        integer chan = (integer)llList2String(msgs, 2);
        msgs = llDeleteSubList(msgs, 0, 2);
        llDialog(agent, prompt, msgs, chan);
    }
}

//script named "radial animation"
float interval = 0.1;
float originalsize = 1.0;
float rate = 5;
integer maxpoints = 48;
integer points = 23; //1 to 48
integer multiplier = 15;
integer lines;
string url = "https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34887/make-a-circle-illusion-animation/34891";

list cylinders;
list spheres;
float angle;
integer running;
integer chan;
integer lh;

desc(integer on)
{
    if(on)
    {
        string desc = 
            (string)points + "," +
            (string)multiplier + "," +
            (string)running + "," +
            (string)lines
            ;

        llSetLinkPrimitiveParamsFast(1, [PRIM_DESC, desc]);
    }
    else
    {
        list params = llCSV2List(llList2String(llGetLinkPrimitiveParams(1, [PRIM_DESC]), 0));
        points = (integer)llList2String(params, 0);
        multiplier = (integer)llList2String(params, 1);
        running = (integer)llList2String(params, 2);
        lines = (integer)llList2String(params, 3);
    }    
}

init()
{
    llSetLinkPrimitiveParamsFast(LINK_ALL_OTHERS, [PRIM_POS_LOCAL, ZERO_VECTOR, 
        PRIM_COLOR, ALL_SIDES, <1, 1, 1>, 0]);
    integer num = llGetNumberOfPrims();
    integer i;
    for(i = 2; i <= num; i++)
    {
        string name = llGetLinkName(i);

        if(name == "cyl")
            cylinders += [i];
        else if(name == "sphere")
            spheres += [i];
    }  

    vector size = llGetScale();
    float scale = size.x/originalsize;

    float r = size.x/4;
    vector cylindersize = <0.01*scale, 0.01*scale, r*4>;
    float arc = 180.0/points;

    for(i = 0; i < points; i++)
    {
        float angle = i*arc;
        rotation rot = llEuler2Rot(<0, 90, 0>*DEG_TO_RAD)*llEuler2Rot(<0, 0, angle>*DEG_TO_RAD);

        integer cyl = llList2Integer(cylinders, i);
        integer sphere = llList2Integer(spheres, i);

        llSetLinkPrimitiveParamsFast(1, [PRIM_LINK_TARGET, cyl, PRIM_POS_LOCAL, ZERO_VECTOR, PRIM_ROT_LOCAL, rot, PRIM_SIZE, cylindersize, PRIM_COLOR, ALL_SIDES, <0.25, 0.25, 0.25>, 0.5*lines,
        PRIM_LINK_TARGET, sphere, PRIM_COLOR, ALL_SIDES, <0.25 + llFrand(0.75), 0.25 + llFrand(0.75), 0.25 + llFrand(0.75)>, 1
        ]);
    }
}

run()
{
    vector size = llGetScale();
    float scale = size.x/originalsize;

    float r = size.x/2;
    vector spheresize = <0.06, 0.06, 0.02>*scale;
    float arc = 180.0/points;
    list params;
    integer i;
    for(i = 0; i < points; i++)
    {

        float x = r*llCos((angle + i*arc*multiplier)*DEG_TO_RAD);

        vector pos = <x, 0, 0>*llEuler2Rot(<0, 0, i*arc>*DEG_TO_RAD);
        rotation rot = llEuler2Rot(<0, 0, i*arc>*DEG_TO_RAD);
        integer link = llList2Integer(spheres, i);
        params += [PRIM_LINK_TARGET, link, PRIM_POS_LOCAL, pos,  
            PRIM_ROT_LOCAL, rot,
            PRIM_SIZE, spheresize
            //PRIM_COLOR, ALL_SIDES, <1, 1, 1>, 1
            ];
    }   

    llSetLinkPrimitiveParamsFast(1, params);
}

dialog(key id)
{
    string runningstring;
    if(running)
        runningstring = "notrunning";
    else
        runningstring = "running";

    string linesstring;
    if(lines)
        linesstring = "nolines";
    else
        linesstring = "lines";
    string prompt = "\npoints: " + (string)points + "\nmultiplier: " + (string)multiplier;
    string buttons = runningstring + ",points+,points-,reset,multiplier+,multiplier-," + linesstring + ",www";
    llMessageLinked(1, 0, (string)id + "," + prompt + "," + (string)chan + "," + buttons, "");
    //llDialog(id, prompt, llCSV2List(buttons), chan);
}

default
{
    state_entry()
    {
        chan = (integer)("0x" + llGetSubString((string)llGetKey(), -8, -1));
        lh = llListen(chan, "", "", "");

        desc(FALSE);
        init();
        run();
        llSetTimerEvent(interval);
    }

    on_rez(integer param)
    {
        llListenRemove(lh);
        chan = (integer)("0x" + llGetSubString((string)llGetKey(), -8, -1));
        lh = llListen(chan, "", "", "");
    }

    touch_start(integer total_number)
    {
        key id = llDetectedKey(0);
        dialog(id);
    }

    timer()
    {
        if(!running)
            return;

        angle += rate;
        if(angle > 360)
            angle -= 360;
        else if(angle < 0)
            angle += 360;

        run();
    }

    listen(integer channel, string name, key id, string msg)
    {
        if(msg == "points+")
        {
            if(points < maxpoints)
            {
                points++;
                desc(TRUE);
                llResetScript();            
            }
        }
        else if(msg == "points-")
        {
            if(points > 0)
            {
                points--;
                desc(TRUE);
                llResetScript();
            }
        }        
        else if(msg == "multiplier+")
        {
            multiplier++;
            desc(TRUE);
        }
        else if(msg == "multiplier-")
        {
            multiplier--;
            desc(TRUE);
        }
        else if(msg == "running")
        {
            running = TRUE;
            desc(TRUE);
        }
        else if(msg == "notrunning")
        {
            running = FALSE;
            desc(TRUE);
        }
        else if(msg == "lines")
        {
            lines = TRUE;
            desc(TRUE);
            llResetScript();
        }
        else if(msg == "nolines")
        {
            lines = FALSE;
            desc(TRUE);
            llResetScript();
        }
        else if(msg == "reset")
            llResetScript();
        else if(msg == "www")
            llRegionSayTo(id, 0, url);
        dialog(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## PICO-8, 271 chars

```lua
camera(-64,-64)p=8::_::s=p.." lines"cls(7)circfill(0,0,50,0)for l=0,.5,.5/p do
u=flr(50*cos(l))v=flr(50*sin(l))line(u,-v,-u,v,5)end
?s,-#s*2,-60
for l=0,.5,.5/p do
u=flr(48*cos(l))v=flr(48*sin(l))q=cos(l-t()/4)circfill(u*q,-v*q,2,7)end
flip()p+=flr(btnp()/16+1)%3-1goto _
```

The code for this is so short, I could post it as a tweet. In fact, [I just did](https://twitter.com/WinslowJosiah/status/1196771078166732803).

[image: A gif capture from PICO-8.]

You can also change the number of lines with the X and Z keys. (Oddly enough, due to a side effect of how division by 0 is handled in PICO-8, 0 lines acts exactly like 1 line. Negative numbers of lines don't show up.)

Ungolfed source:

```lua
lines=8

while true do
 cls(7)
 -- draw circle
 circfill(64,64,50,0)
 -- draw lines
 for l=0,.5,.5/lines do
  u=flr(50*cos(l))
  v=flr(50*sin(l))
  line(64+u,64-v,64-u,64+v,5)
 end
 -- center string
 s=lines.." lines"
 print(s,64-#s*2,4)
 -- draw points
 for l=0,.5,.5/lines do
  u=flr(48*cos(l))
  v=flr(48*sin(l))
  -- one full turn every 4 secs
  q=cos(l-t()/4)
  circfill(64+u*q,64-v*q,2,7)
 end
 flip()
 -- -1 if only ❎ is pressed
 -- +1 if only ️ is pressed
 --  0 otherwise
 lines+=flr(btnp()/16+1)%3-1
end
```